# Getting all tinymce content in post method

Tags: php, xml, tinymce

I have a xml file with data

```
<ul>
  <li><info>CSS text formatting </info></li>
  <li><info>Text loaded from a XML</info></li>
  <li><info>Scrolls with easing</info></li>
</ul>
```

For editing the content i have used tinymce editor.For editing i am parsing the xml file and putit in a textarea that is for timymce edtor.In the editor i am getting the `<info>` tag after the `<li>` tag.But when iam submitting the value the `<info>` tag is not getting.How i can get `<li><info>Text loaded from a XML</info></li>` when i am submitting the form.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in tinymce configuration

```
extended_valid_elements : "info",
custom_elements: "info",
```

Answer (score 1):

`info` is not a valid html tag.

Comment: Is their any way to get all the html tag

Comment: As stated, info is not an HTML tag. Thus, you are getting all HTML tags.

Comment: How can i get '<li><info>Text loaded from a XML</info></li>'

Comment: Either you cant, or you shouldn't. Only use valid HTML tags.